# How to find and replace items not preceded or followed by specific characters with sed?

Tags: bash, replace, sed

How can I restrict find and replace to replace items, but not if the character immediately before it is "A", "B", or "C" or the character immediately after it is "X", "Y", or "Z". E.g. given these input lines, if "cat" is to be replaced with replaced with "pet":

- "There is a cat." → "These is a pet."
- "There is Acat." is unchanged, because "A' is found before.
- "There is catY." is unchanged, because "Y' is found after.
- "There is CcatX." is unchanged, because "C' is found before and "X" after.

Answer (score 4):

This sed should work for you:

```
sed -r 's/(^|[^ABC])cat\>/\1pet/g; s/\<cat([^XYZ]|$)/pet\1/g' file
```

**Testing:**

```
sed -r 's/(^|[^ABC])cat\>/\1pet/g; s/\<cat([^XYZ]|$)/pet\1/g' <<< 'cat is a cat is a cat'
pet is a pet is a pet
```

Comment: Test with `cat is a cat is a cat`.

Comment: @cforbish: I tested with that input and got: `pet is a pet is a pet`

Comment: I get `pet is a cat is a pet`.  I gave you an up vote anyway.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\bcat\b/pet/g' file
```

or:

```
sed 's/\<cat\>/pet/g' file
```

or in light of comments:

```
sed -r 's/(\b|[^ABC])cat(\b|[^XYZ])/\1pet\2/g' file
```

Comment: As per OP `"there are cats"` should become `"there are pets"` but this won't do that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your text is in a file called `text.txt`.  This will work:

```
sed -i 's/\(.*[^ABC]\|^\)cat\([^XYZ].*\|$\)/\1pet\2/g' text.txt
```

What is happening (from [tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-regular-expressions.htm), [man sed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed) and [sed regex](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html)):

```
-i         Edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
s/???/???/ Or s/regexp/replacement/, Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.
/          Field separator to 's'.
^          Match first character on line.
\(         Start back reference.
.          Match any character.
[^ABC]     Do not match any charcter (^ = don't) in this list.
\|         Matches regex1 or regexp2 (do not match ABC or match start of line).
\)         End back reference.
cat        Match cat
\1         The first back reference.
\2         The second back reference.
g          Replace all matches, not just the first match.
```

Comment: Test with the input `cat is a cat`

Answer (score 1):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) might be a better idea since it supports lookahead/lookbehind:

```
perl -lape 's/(?<![ABC])cat(?![XYZ])/pet/' input
```